# Controling the display of validation summary on client and server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm trying to use a Asp.net MVC ValidationSummary wrap on a Bootstrap alert code, like this (razor):

```
if (!this.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
<div class="alert alert-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="alert-heading">Some error(s) occurred:</h4>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
</div>
}
```

This is working fine with server side validation, but with my view models with annotations cause client side validation and my "if" above doesn't seem to work with the client side.

So... how can I test for client side validation messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out how ValidationSummary is done in [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/)

`@Html.Bootstrap().ValidationSummary()`

This will work fine for the server side validation. For the client side validation you need to include a javascript file: [TwitterBootstrapMvcJs-3.0.0.js](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Scripts/TwitterBootstrapMvcJs-3.0.0.js)